# jQuery: Image fading to another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fade, out

I have the following code in jQuery:

```
if (klick = true) $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png").fadeIn();
});
```

The changing of the image now works so:
- Image1 fade-out
- No image is displayed
- Image2 fade-in

How can I fix this, that the images fading together, without a lil time with no image between them?

Here's the site where you can see what I mean:

http://anthraxbeats.com/pages/biography.html

When you're hovering on a image, theres a short empty space before the image loads in.
How can I fix it?

Comment: How can I do that? In the code?

Answer (score 1):

Use two different images. Have them cover the same space by setting their css properties "position: absolute". Fade the first one out while setting the other one to false. You may need a proper container with position: relative as position: absolute may cause them to behave...unexpectedly.

```
#container{
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
.img1, .img2{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding [queue: false] to the animation will allow for multiple animations at the same time

```
var $theOtherThing = $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png");

if(klick === true){
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": "0"
     }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
     });
    $theOtherThing.animate({
        "opacity": "1"
     }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try preloading your image outside of the click handler. Something like this should work:

```
(new Image()).src = "../img/daniel_effects.png";
```